# Restoring a view after orientation change

Tags: android, fragment

I have a `Fragment` that contain `EditText` and `ImageView` that's need to be retain across configuration changes so I tried to save the text and the bitmap via `onSaveInstanceState`.

But when I rotate the device problems start.

the text i saved overlap with the hint of `EditText` and the bitmap overlap with the original placeholder of the `ImageView`.

I've tried to do the restore from various methods (`onCreateView` , `onViewCreated` and `onViewStateRestored`). But still the same problem remain.

so instead of `onSaveInstanceState` I used `setRetainInstance(true)` and the problem remain with the text overlap the hint in `EditText`.

So where did I do wrong? AND how to solve this.

this is the `EditText`:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/username_editext"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/enter_ur_name"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:lines="1"
    android:padding="8dp"/>
```

and this is the `ImageView`:

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_above="@id/username_editext"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/profile"
    />
```

and here is the code for save & restore via `bundle`:

```
public void onViewStateRestored(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);

    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        Bitmap map = (Bitmap) savedInstanceState.getParcelable(BITMAP_KEY);
        if(map != null)
            mProfile.setImageBitmap(map);
        String name = savedInstanceState.getString(USERNAME_KEY);
        if(name != null)
            mUsernameEditext.setText(name);
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    if(isPhotoUploaded) {
        Bitmap map = ((BitmapDrawable)mProfile.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        outState.putParcelable(BITMAP_KEY, map);
    }

    if(!mUsernameEditext.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
        outState.putString(USERNAME_KEY , mUsernameEditext.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

`Edit 1:`
This is the complete layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".UsernameFragment">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_above="@id/username_text_input_layout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/profile"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/username_text_input_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/enter_ur_name"
        >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username_editext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:lines="1"
            android:padding="8dp"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/upload_photo_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/upload_photo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/username_text_input_layout"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next_btn"
        android:layout_below="@id/upload_photo_btn"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/next"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Issue is with your layout, sounds like that is not dynamic. Try adding scrollbar and add fix margin/padding between the child. Other way you can create two layout 1) layout 2)layout-land. Better you share you layout xml file. can suggest accordingly

Comment: What do you mean by `dynamic` , like not using `xml` file?

Comment: Share layout xml file, can suggest accordingly

Comment: @KrishnaSharma I edit the question with the complete code

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot where is overlapping issue ?

Comment: I have found the answer by creating the fragment using tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that if I use tag instead of container's id the issue is gone.

This is the code before to build the `fragment`:

```
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (manager.findFragmentById(R.id.container) == null) {
        usernameFragment = UsernameFragment.newInstance();
        manager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container , usernameFragment)
                .commit();
    }
```

And this is the code now:

```
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (manager.findFragmentByTag("user_name") == null) {
        usernameFragment = UsernameFragment.newInstance();
        manager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container , usernameFragment , "user_name")
                .commit();
    }
```

I still don't know why the first code make overlap in views if rotated. and returned null if I call getter of any view in fragment